# Rewrite url в Nginx

Tags: nginx

Привет. Хочу переписать расположение папок в своём проекте. Сейчас структура такова:

- Кто-то заходит на главную страницу и в меню выбирает страницу /about/. В директории сайта это выглядит, как `/about/index.php`, а в адресной строке отображается, как `example.com/about`

Что я хочу сделать, так это переместить все индексные файлы страниц в отдельную папку для упрощения навигации:

- Кто-то заходит на главную страницу, выбирает страницу /about/. В директории сайта это выглядит, как /pages/about.php и после перехода в адресной строке отображается, как example.com/about

Как это сделать при помощи Nginx, если можно вообще? По-факту, нужно просто определять, находится ли запрашиваемая страница в папке `/pages/` и подставлять имя файла без `.php`, но умеет ли это делать Nginx - без понятия.

Comment: дополнил ответ upd

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте добавить в корень файл с названием `.htaccess` c содержимым

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages?/$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Вторая строчка - исключения на «переадресацию». Результат «из коробки» не гарантирую, но вам точно стоит думать в этом направлении.

А вообще для подобной реализации так называемого ЧПУ люди используют фрейморки, например [Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com).

---

### UPD

Ранее не встречался с NGINX, не знал что он не работает с `.htaccess`, но нашел ответ в [первом ответе гугла](http://g.zeos.in/?q=nginx%20htaccess) **за вас**.

Берете следующий код:

```
# nginx configuration
location / {
   rewrite ^(.*)$ /pages?/$1.php break;
}
```

и размещаете его в секции [server {}](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server) конфигурационного файла nginx.

Опять таки не ручаюсь за верность регулярного выражения - допилите сами руками, если не заработает сразу.

Comment: Nginx в упор не видит никаких .htaccess

Comment: @KAGGDesign дополнил ответ